# Does R produce warnings when it runs out of space from read.csv command

Tags: r, csv, memory, memory-management

This question is pretty simple and maybe even dumb, but I can't find an answer on google. I'm trying to read a .txt file into R using this command:

```
data <- read.csv("perm2test.txt", sep="\t", header=FALSE, row.names=1, col.names=paste("V", seq_len(max(count.fields("perm2test.txt", sep="\t"))), sep=""), fill=TRUE)
```

The reason I have the col.names command is because every line in my .txt file has a different number of observations. I've tested this on a much smaller file and it works. However, when I run it on my actual dataset (which is only 48MB), I'm not sure if it is working... The reason I'm not sure is because I haven't received an error message, yet it has been "running" for over 24 hours at this point (just the read.csv command above). Is it possible that it has run out of memory and it just doesn't output a warning?

I've looked around and I know people say there are functions out there to reduce the size and remove lines that aren't needed, etc. but to be honest I don't think this file is THAT big, and unfortunately I do need every line in the file... (it's actually only 70 lines, but some lines contain as much as 100k entries, while others may only have say 100). Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: (1) I don't understand what your `col.names` argument has to do with different rows having different numbers of observations, (2) `fill = TRUE` is likely greatly expanding the resulting size of the data frame: 70 x 100k, (3) regardless, that's far too long to be running, even for `read.table`. Force it to stop and try some other stuff (`fread` maybe).

Comment: ```read.csv()``` is intended for .csv files. I think you're looking for ```read.table()``` instead. Can you provide a sample of your text file?

Comment: What analysis do you want to do on this data?  A data frame may not be optimal.  Perhaps use `readLines()` and process the 70 lines in a different way, perhaps using `strsplit()` ?

Comment: What does this return: `table(count.fields("perm2test.txt", sep="\t"))`?

Comment: read.table() doesn't work as it expects all lines to have the same number of entries. The col.names() assigns a numbered column header up to the line with the largest number of entries, I use that as read.csv() will only take the largest line from the first 5 lines and arbitrarily decide that as the maximum number of columns for the rest of the table (whereas some later lines require much larger columns)

Comment: @BondedDust It returns:
1st line: `2   10001   20000   20001   40000   90000  440000 1990000`
2nd line:`60     4       1          1           1           2           1           1` (I don't know how to start a new line in this comment....)

Comment: You should have added it as an edit. This suggests you have sixty lines with 2 items, 4 with 10001 items; 2 with 90000 items and one each with the remaining numbers of items including one with almost 2 million items. The fact that they all seem close to multiples of 10000 makes me think you don't really know what the proper separator is. I doubt that it is tabs.

Comment: @BondedDust They are separated by tabs, and the reason they are in multiples of 10000 is because i was running a resampling test on a dataset that resamples at exactly 10000x for each variable. Some variables are coerced during the processing, which is why not every variable ended up with the same number of "observations" now. I know it sounds strange, but the goal is to generate a boxplot with this data, which is why i want it in a data frame

Comment: Well then... you must have forgotten to append `'\n'` at the end of each group of 10,000 items when you were writing to the file.

Comment: @BondedDust ... I don't want new lines... Each variable is resampled 10000 times, if variables are related to each other under certain criteria, they are grouped together into one category (the largest category being the one with the most variables and hence the largest line). I don't want then separated into individual lines as the whole point is to group them and plot each group as a single boxplot (ie, each line forms its separate box when plotted, some lines are essentially empty as the variables did not pass the test to be resampled, and should have no box)

Comment: I think you're very confused about `read.table` and `read.csv`. `read.csv` _is_ `read.table`, just with different defaults. Everything that `read.csv` does can be done (and in fact, _is_ done) with a call to `read.table`.

Comment: You're also mistaken about what `col.names` does. `fill = TRUE` is sufficient to ensure colnames numbered from 1 to the max number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously untested but should give you some code to modify:

```
datL <- readLines("perm2test.txt") # one line per group
# may want to exclude some lines but question is unclear
listL <- lapply(datL, function(L) read.delim(text=L, colCasses="numeric") )
# This is a list of values by group
dfL  <- data.frame( vals = unlist(listL), 
# Now build a grouping vector that is associated with each bundle of values
                    groups= rep( LETTERS[1:length(listL)] ,
                                 sapply(listL, length) )
 # Might have been able to do that last maneuver with `stack`.

library(lattice)
bwplot( vals ~ groups, data=dfL)
```